# Flutter With Firebase Phone Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter

**I/BiChannelGoogleApi(15179): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@7a473f**

I am getting this error when i press the login button . Also , i added the correct googleservices.json in app folder in flutter

Can anyone please tell me the reason why is it occuring so ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the SHA 1 in the Firebase console. If you didn’t you can get the SHA 1 by

> keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: I added it to the firebase console

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your SHA1 and SHA256 with `gradlew signingReport`

Comment: Thank You for the answer but i added the sha1 as well as sha256 in the app settings in the firebase console. But it didn't work yet .

Comment: Are you sure you enabled phone sign in in firebase?

Comment: Yes 100% sure . If u have the latest code of phone authentication using firebase in flutter then can u please provide a link to it ?